# Repairing a leaking 1/2" shut off gate valve under kitchen sink

Tags: plumbing, repair, water

Which is the proper washer to repair a 1/2" shut off gate valve: rubber, fiber or nylon? The valve is a cheap home depot product. I tried  a flat thick rubber washer; it held for about 5 minutes then started spraying from around the washer. Also should I use thread tape or compound on the threads of the valve before putting it back together?

Comment: Post a picture of the valve.

Comment: Home Depot doesn't make valves (and it's not their fault that consumers demand the cheap crap). How about a brand name or photo?